# Use crypto with async / await syntax with typescript

Tags: typescript

I have been trying to figure out a way to use `crypto` module with `async await` syntax while preserving all typescript declarations. For example, `randomFill` has three function overrides (inside `@types/node`):

```
function randomFill<T extends NodeJS.ArrayBufferView>(
    buffer: T,
    callback: (err: Error | null, buf: T) => void,
): void;

function randomFill<T extends NodeJS.ArrayBufferView>(
    buffer: T,
    offset: number,
    callback: (err: Error | null, buf: T) => void,
): void;

function randomFill<T extends NodeJS.ArrayBufferView>(
    buffer: T,
    offset: number,
    size: number,
    callback: (err: Error | null, buf: T) => void,
): void;
```

If I use to use `blubird promisify` method, then only a part of the typescript declarations will be preserved (if you hover over exported `randomFill` method in an IDE you will see that I mean):

```
import {promisify} from 'bluebird';
import {randomFill as randomFillNative } from 'crypto';

export const randomFill = promisify<NodeJS.ArrayBufferView, NodeJS.ArrayBufferView, number>(randomFillNative)
```

The same is true for `util promisify` method:

```
import {promisify} from 'util';
import {randomFill as randomFillNative } from 'crypto';

export const randomFill = promisify<NodeJS.ArrayBufferView, number, NodeJS.ArrayBufferView>(randomFillNative)
```

Here is what I get when promisifying it:

[image]

**Is there a way to easily wrap crypto methods into promises while preserving typescript delcarations?**

Comment: You should not provide any explicit generic arguments. TS should infer them. It works in TS playground.

Comment: Added edit that explains how it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to use async/await for crypto operations in the beginning? Cryptography is made of synchronous in-memory math/logic operations. It won't take benefits from async programming

Comment: It won't? If that's true, then thank you, I will it syncronously, it's just seems weird about why then nodejs provides async versions with callbacks?

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ That depends on the function. If it's really just number crunching in a hash or encryption function, you may be correct. I don't know how `randomFill` is implemented. On *ix systems, it might for instance read from `/dev/random` (if available). And tbh. that there are sync and async versions of a function in the API is a strong indication, that there is some async code happening in the background, otherwise the async variant wouldn't make any sense ...

Answer (score 0):

You can call `promisify` for each overload of `randomFill`. Because with `promisify` you are creating exactly one async function with the given signature (input parameters and type for the promise).

```
const rf1 = promisify<NodeJS.ArrayBufferView, NodeJS.ArrayBufferView>(randomFillNative)
const rf2 = promisify<NodeJS.ArrayBufferView, number, NodeJS.ArrayBufferView>(randomFillNative)
const rf3 = promisify<NodeJS.ArrayBufferView, number, number, NodeJS.ArrayBufferView>(randomFillNative)
```

Another possibility is, you do the promisify yourself and create the respecive overloads

```
function randomFill<T extends NodeJS.ArrayBufferView>(
  buffer: T
): Promise<T>;

function randomFill<T extends NodeJS.ArrayBufferView>(
  buffer: T,
  offset: number,
): Promise<T>;

function randomFill<T extends NodeJS.ArrayBufferView>(
  buffer: T,
  offset: number,
  size: number
): Promise<T>;

function randomFill<T extends NodeJS.ArrayBufferView>(
  buffer: T,
  offset?: number,
  size?: number
): Promise<T> {
  if (offset === undefined)
    return new Promise<T>((res, rej) => {
      randomFillNative(buffer, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) return rej(err);
        res(buf);
      })
    })
  else if (size === undefined)
    return new Promise<T>((res, rej) => {
      randomFillNative(buffer, offset, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) return rej(err);
        res(buf);
      })
    })
  else
    return new Promise<T>((res, rej) => {
      randomFillNative(buffer, offset, size, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) return rej(err);
        res(buf);
      })
    })
}
```

I know it's cumbersome, but I don't think, typescript and promisify are currently able to extract the type-information from all available overloads.